# Complex integration vs real integration

Tags: integration

In real analysis we know that integration of a function from a to b gives us an area bounded by x axis and X equal to a line and X equal to b line and the function but I am confused in complex analysis what is the actual meaning of complex integration? Is there any geometrical meaning or geometrical interpretation? Can we connect real integration and complex integration in any way? Please help.

Comment: Are you talking about integrating functions $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$? In this case, we can only take line integrals over curves in the complex plane. This is similar to taking line integrals over curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

There is no complex version of the "usual" integration over the real line.

Comment: And yes: we certainly can connect between complex and real integration...to our great joy. Some of the most powerful ways to evaluate certain kinds of real integrals, both trigonometric and in general improper integrals, is by means of complex integration.